# Mysterious parameter -r in Nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon, dotenv

I've been searching on how to reload env on the development environment while using `Nodemon`.

The command that spread all over on the internet is `nodemon -r dotenv/config bin/www.js`, this is actually working, but look at the command, what is the `-r` thing? I'm out of curiosity.

I've been searching on the official documentation with no luck. https://github.com/remy/nodemon/wiki

Anyone care to explain, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found an answer.

Quoted from `Nodemon` docs:

> nodemon wraps your application, so you can pass all the arguments you would normally pass to your app
>   https://github.com/remy/nodemon#usage

So basically any arguments that **unknown** to `Nodemon` will redirect to Node.js app, so `-r` is passed to the Node.js, which means "Require module".

See: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/cli.html#cli_r_require_module

Answer (score 0):

`-r` is not a valid argument option
Take a look at

https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/lib/cli/parse.js

for all supported options

Comment: On which line number?

Comment: type nodemon --help, there is no -r param supported by nodemon

Comment: Within `nodemonOption` function at 105 line, you can read all the options available. I mean you can simply search by `-r` there is no option with `-r`